# jQuery expand element from center not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make a zoom-like effect on hover event in a gallery exercise. What I need is for an image to seem to expand from its center, not down and right. If I understood correctly, I need to move it half way left and up for this to work. Also, I'm using `em`, so I try to convert `em` to pixels here.

Relevant html:

```
<div id="gallery">
  <img src="img/cool1.gif">
  <img src="img/cool2.gif" id="gal2">
  <img src="img/cool3.gif" id="gal3">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#gallery {
  width: 31em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#gallery img {
  width: 10em;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

#gal2 {
  margin-left: 10em;
}

#gal3 {
  margin-left: 20em;
}
```

Finally, jQuery:

```
var fontSize = $("#gallery img").css("font-size");//equal to 1em?
var fontInt = parseInt(fontSize);
        
var t = $("#gallery img").position().top;
var tNew = t - (5 * fontInt);//top position
        
var l = $("#gallery img").position().left;
var lNew = l - (5 * fontInt);//left position


$("#gallery img").hover(
    function() {
        
        $(this).stop().css("zIndex", "1").animate({
            height : "20em",
            width : "20em",
            top : tNew,
            left : lNew
            
        }, 400);
    }, //end mouseover
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height : "10em",
            width : "10em",
            top : t,
            left : l,
            zIndex : "0"
        }, 400);
    } //end mouseout
);//end hover
```

**edit 1** Images expand and change position, but not as expected. Also, they don't return on mouseout. Thanks to Racil Hilan for solving em-px conversion problem!

**edit 2** Problem moslty solved by fixing variable scope – position values moved before hover() function. The only remaining bug is that the pictures escape to the top right corner of the body before returning to their place on first interaction. Afterwards, it runs as expected. Also, could somebody explain why this works when the fontInt variable is multiplied by five, not by 10?

**edit 3 – solution** As Mauricio Santamaria said below, just add the css() function setting top and left parameters before hover on #gallery img element like so:

```
$("#gallery img").css({"top" : t, "left" : l}).hover(...);
```

The rest stays the same.

I improvised a fiddle for this, too: http://jsfiddle.net/dzenesiz/wudw5hmu/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `$(this).css("font-size");` returns the size with the unit (e.g. 16px) which is not a number and the calculation results in a `NaN`.

A quick solution is to parse it to an integer like this:

```
var fontSize = parseInt($(this).css("font-size")); //equal to 1em?
```

Comment: So I should... parse it somehow? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

to remove the "jump" when first interaction you should set "top" and "left" on your css, this removes that behavior (tested on your fiddle with 8px or 0.4em equivalent to your initial image size), and for your question about why 5 gets your desired result its that the result of that operation (5 * fontInt) gives you the initial value of images ie. 100px (10em), and that's the amount for top and left that you need to make it zoom from center. (the initial value for fontSize is 20em, initial t =8, so  8-100 = -92, the right value taking in account the margin  )